# What are $\sigma$ and $\tau$ in $n = 2^{\sigma(n)}\,\tau(n)$ called?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation, terminology

Every non-zero integer $n$ can be factored uniquely as $2^s t$, where $s$ is a non-negative integer, and $t$ is an odd integer.

In other words, there exist functions $\sigma:\mathbb{Z}\backslash \{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}^{\geq 0}$ and $\tau:\mathbb{Z}\backslash \{0\}\rightarrow 2\mathbb{Z}+1$ such that, for every $n\in \mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}$,

$$n = 2^{\sigma(n)}\,\tau(n)$$

If the functions $\sigma$ and $\tau$ have names, what are they?

Comment: $\sigma(n)$ (more usually denoted $\operatorname{ord}_2(n)$ or $\nu_2(n)$) can be called the [_$2$-adic valuation of $n$_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order). Not sure about $\tau(n)$.

Comment: I wouldn't call them $\sigma$ and $\tau$ since those are commonly used for specific functions in number theory. What you call $\tau$ I'd call the "odd part" function, but I don't know if it has a real name.